# Como trazer data sem registro Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma consulta SQL somando valores de cada dia, retornando somente os dias que tem valores. Porem gostaria de apresentar também os dias que não tiveram registros.

***Consulta:***

```
SELECT DATA, 
       SUM(VALOR)
FROM TABELA1
WHERE CONTA = '176087'
GROUP BY DATA
```

***Saída:***

```
02/10/2015  36312
05/10/2015  25382
06/10/2015  3655
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução passa por criar uma estrutura auxiliar com o intervalo de datas para o qual queres gerar os resultados.

Se desejares utilizar esta solução, tens várias alternativas (a lista não é exaustiva):

- Criar uma tabela física na base de dados que contém, por exemplo,
  todas as datas desde o ano 2000;
- Criar uma tabela temporária com um
  intervalo de datas;
- Usar uma [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx);

Vou deixar aqui uma solução usando uma CTE.

```
create table tabela1
(
  conta     nvarchar(05),
  [data]    datetime,
  valor     float
);
insert into tabela1(conta, [data], valor)values
('12345', '2016-05-25', 1),
('12345', '2016-05-26', 3),
('12345', '2016-05-26', 1),
('12345', '2016-05-28', 2),
('12345', '2016-05-28', 3);

with Datas as (
     select cast('2016-05-25' as date) [data]
     union all
     select dateadd(dd, 1, t.[data]) 
       from Datas t
      where dateadd(dd, 1, t.[data]) <= '2016-05-31'
) -- gera uma view descartável com o intervalo de datas entre 25 a 31 de Maio
select d.[data],
       isnull(sum(valor), 0) sum_valor
  from Datas d
left join tabela1 t
   on t.[data] = d.[data]
  and t.conta = '12345'
group by d.[data]
order by d.[data]
```

A instrução anterior irá gerar o seguinte output:

```
data         sum_valor
2016-05-25   1
2016-05-26   4
2016-05-27   0
2016-05-28   5
2016-05-29   0
2016-05-30   0
2016-05-31   0
```

Fica aqui o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ee0a/1)

Comment: Não tinha reparado que já tinhas encontrado uma solução. Deixo, ainda assim, aqui a resposta caso alguém precise no futuro (uma vez que a resposta anterior não responde à pergunta).

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso?

```
SELECT DATA, COALESCE(SUM(VALOR),0) FROM TABELA1 WHERE CONTA = '176087' GROUP BY DATA
```

Comment: então Diego, eu gostaria de demonstrar junto com o resultado apresentado as datas que nao tiveram registro, nessa minha sentença só traz as datas que tiveram registro no banco

Comment: Editei a resposta, teste agora.

Comment: Esse que me passou também trás somente os dias que tiveram os registros

Comment: Tenta alterar o COALESCE para IFNULL então.

Comment: ainda não funcionou, tentei algo do tipo, somente a CT tras as datas, quando relaciono vem somente as datas com valores

Comment: with dateRange as
(
  select dt = startDate
  where startDate < endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(dd, 1, dt) <= @endDate
)
/*
select convert(varchar(MAX),dt,103)
from dateRange*/
select
    convert(varchar(MAX),d.dt,103),
    COALESCE(SUM(VALLAN),NULL)
from dateRange as d
LEFT join ARQ032 as t on t.DATLAN = d.dt
WHERE 
    t.NUMCON = '176087'
GROUP BY 
    d.dt

Comment: Testei o select da pergunta aqui e traz 0 onde não tem valor. Testa no SQL só ele para ver.

Comment: eu testei, ele só tras as datas que tem valor

ficou assim: 
SELECT DATLAN, COALESCE(SUM(VALLAN),0) 
FROM ARQ032 
WHERE NUMCON = '176087' 
AND DATLAN >= '2016-01-01'
AND DATLAN <= '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY DATLAN
ORDER BY DATLAN

Comment: O campo valor é null ou tem zero gravado?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40394/discussion-between-diego-and-rafael).

Comment: ele não tem movimento, não tem registro. no exemplo que mandei estou somando os valores que tem datas, as outras datas do mês não tem registro no banco